# Mobile navigation menu from apple website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to build the animations from the new apple website for mobile devices.
To describe the effect, basically the user can tap onto the left upper corner menu, then the two parallel lines will transform into an "x", which shows the previously hidden nav that can be swiped right to reveal more content. 
http://www.apple.com/de/ - viewed on  my chrome device tools.

```js
$('.header-top input').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '=') {
        $(this).val('x');
        $('.header-bot').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).val('=');
        $('.header-bot').show();
    }
})
```

```css
body {
    margin:auto;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.header {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size:2em;
    height: 50px;
}
.header-top {
    height: 50px;
}
.header-top input {
    float:left;
    font-size:inherit;
    padding:0;
    border-style:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.header-bot {
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.header-bot li {
    margin-left:1em;
    float: left;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #999;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.header-bot li:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-top">
            <input type="button" value="=">
        </div>
        <div class="header-bot">
            <li>google</li>
            <li>yahoo</li>
            <li>msn</li>
            <li>codingforums</li>
            <li>jsfiddle</li>
            <li>google</li>
            <li>yahoo</li>
            <li>msn</li>
            <li>codingforums</li>
            <li>jsfiddle</li>
            <li>google</li>
            <li>yahoo</li>
            <li>msn</li>
            <li>codingforums</li>
            <li>jsfiddle</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ck2psk8y/2/)
this demo working only in firefox even apple website provide this functionality in firefox not in chrome and safari.i tested ...

```js
$('.header-bot').hide(); 
$('#gh-svg-icons').on('click', function () {
 var flag= $(this).attr('aria-expanded');
 //alert(flag);
 if(flag=='true')
 {
  $(this).addClass('gh-svg-wrapper_click');
  
  $("#svg_first").attr("class", "gh-svg gh-svg-top");
  $('#svg_third').attr('class','gh-svg-rect');
  $("#svg_second").attr("class", "gh-svg gh-svg-bottom");
  
  
  $(this).attr('aria-expanded','false');
  
  $('.header-bot').show();
 }
 else
 {
  $(this).removeClass('gh-svg-wrapper_click');
  $("#svg_first").attr("class", "gh-svg");
  $('#svg_third').attr('class','gh-svg-rect gh_svg_rect_top');
  $("#svg_second").attr("class", "gh-svg");
  
  $(this).attr('aria-expanded','true');
  $('.header-bot').hide();
 }
   
});
```

```css
.gh-svg {
 font-size: 18px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute !important;
 top: 0;
 -webkit-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg); 
 -moz-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg); 
 -o-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg); 
 -ms-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg);
 
 -webkit-transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s;
 -moz-transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s;
 -o-transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s;

}
.gh-svg-wrapper {
 display: block;
 height: 2.66667em;
 outline: medium none;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg); 
 -moz-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg); 
 -o-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg); 
 -ms-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg); 
 
 -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s; 
 -moz-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s; 
 -o-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s;

 width: 2.66667em;
}
button {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 0 none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.gh-svg-wrapper_click {
 -webkit-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(90deg); 
 -moz-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(90deg); 
 -o-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(90deg); 
 -ms-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(90deg);

 -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s; 
 -moz-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s; 
 -o-transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s;
 transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99) 0s;

}
.gh-svg-rect-top, .gh-svg-rect-bottom {
 -webkit-transform:  translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); 
 -moz-transform:  translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); 
 -o-transform:  translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); 
 -ms-transform:  translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
 

}
.gh_svg_rect_top {
 -webkit-transform:  translate3d(0px, -8px, 0px); 
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, -8px, 0px); 
 -o-transform:  translate3d(0px, -8px, 0px); 
 -ms-transform:  translate3d(0px, -8px, 0px);
 

}

.gh-svg-top {
 -webkit-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(45deg); 
 -moz-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(45deg); 
 -o-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(45deg); 
 -ms-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(45deg);
 
 
}
.gh-svg-bottom {
 -webkit-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(-45deg); 
 -moz-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(-45deg); 
 -o-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(-45deg); 
 -ms-transform:  translateZ(0px) rotate(-45deg);

}
.header-top input {
    float:left;
    font-size:inherit;
    padding:0;
    border-style:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.header-bot {
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.header-bot li {
    margin-left:1em;
    float: left;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #999;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.header-bot li:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.header-top {
    height: 37px;
}
.header-top input {
    float:left;
    font-size:inherit;
    padding:0;
    border-style:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-top">
<button class="gh-svg-wrapper " id="gh-svg-icons" aria-expanded="true"> 
 <svg id="svg_first" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 96 96" class="gh-svg " enable-background="new 0 0 96 96">
<rect id="svg_third" width="32" height="4" x="32" y="46" class="gh_svg_rect_top gh-svg-rect "/>
</svg> <svg id="svg_second" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 96 96" class="gh-svg " enable-background="new 0 0 96 96">
<rect width="32" height="4" x="32" y="46" class="gh-svg-rect "/>
</svg> </button>
        </div>

<div class="header-bot">
            <li>google</li>
            <li>yahoo</li>
            <li>msn</li>
            <li>codingforums</li>
            <li>jsfiddle</li>
            <li>google</li>
            <li>yahoo</li>
            <li>msn</li>
            <li>codingforums</li>
            <li>jsfiddle</li>
            <li>google</li>
            <li>yahoo</li>
            <li>msn</li>
            <li>codingforums</li>
            <li>jsfiddle</li>
        </div>
```

Comment: I want to use this for my website. I checked how it works on apple but i really don't understand that. This works great on firefox but not on safari and the apple version works on my safari im using. Any updated version for that? would be really helpful. thanks